# QnA Maker - Runtime Error: Authorization Failed

Tags: azure, authorization, runtime, bots, azure-qna-maker

I keep getting the attached runtime error in QnA maker. I could access the Knowledge base fine after creating it but after about an hour i started getting the below error.

[Error Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V2rMU.png)

I have tried everything including trying to delete the knowledge base, create a new one etc and it doesn't delete or create just throws the same error.

Please can someone give me some advice or help. Microsoft recommended I submit a question here.

Thanks

Chris

Answer (score 1):

I faced the smae issue, and to solve it I tried to:

1. First deleted the KB from the My knowledge bases tab.
2. Then went to the https://portal.azure.com and deleted the qna resources.
3. Created a new qna market resource, **but I disabled App insights.**
4. Then created a new KB.

Then it worked

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue from last 3-4 days, today its working fine.

I have deleted the KB from the My knowledge bases and created new one. seems like something update comes from Microsoft. today when i creating KB then found something new in KB UI like default template. below is the url for reference.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/how-to/chit-chat-knowledge-base

its working fine now.