# How to resolve the issue "QnA Maker runtime error Authorization Failed. Authorization Failed" in Azure QnA Maker?

Tags: azure, azure-qna-maker

I am using Azure QA Maker and I can successfully my QA pairs. However, when I loaded the QA pairs and tried to test the service by clicking "Test" on the upper right corner, I got the following error.

[image]

I have tried:

- Delete and create new service.
- Switch between Chrome and Safari.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52511095/9455659

Comment: Possible duplicate of [QnA Maker - Runtime Error: Authorization Failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52500818/qna-maker-runtime-error-authorization-failed)

Comment: @JJ_Wailes Thanks for the response. I went though the solution in the post but still got the same error. Actually, the service worked for sometime and it is not working now again. I am not sure if it is anything wrong the service itself/network issue/anything on my side.

Comment: I think this might be related to my company network, where I got the runtime error and SSL error for the API call. It worked for my under my phone hotspot. Thanks for all the responses above.